# Linux Driver Problem, why ist the Perfomance so bad?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, framerate

Recently I installed Linux Ubuntu 18.04 on an external USB3.0 HDD. Linux is running very smooth and fast, compared to Windows on the same system. But when I want to play 3D-Games like CS:GO or RocketLeague my FPS is dropping very low (CSGO: 40-60FPS, when seeing an enemy 20fps). I spent a whole day to install the driver for my NVIDIA graphics card and tried multiple version of drivers but its not really getting better.

I think that something is wrong with the graphic driver because on Windows the games are running smoothly. I also get a error when i try nvidia-smi:

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

and when i try nvidia-settings it throws this error:

```
    ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).

** Message: 16:34:58.333: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 16:34:58.333: PRIME: is it supported? yes

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot
       be prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

and shows only this in the GUI:

[NVIDIA X Server Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iBNw.png)

**Some Information to my Hardware:**

I have a laptop, normally running WIN10 on the internal HDD. It has a NVIDIA Geforce 930M graphics card and also an intel graphics card.

```
Architektur:                   x86_64
CPU Operationsmodus:           32-bit, 64-bit
Byte-Reihenfolge:              Little Endian
CPU(s):                        4
Liste der Online-CPU(s):       0-3
Thread(s) pro Kern:            2
Kern(e) pro Socket:            2
Sockel:                        1
NUMA-Knoten:                   1
Anbieterkennung:               GenuineIntel
Prozessorfamilie:              6
Modell:                        61
Modellname:                    Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:                      4
CPU MHz:                       2592.794
Maximale Taktfrequenz der CPU: 2700,0000
Minimale Taktfrequenz der CPU: 500,0000
BogoMIPS:                      4393.57
Virtualisierung:               VT-x
L1d Cache:                     32K
L1i Cache:                     32K
L2 Cache:                      256K
L3 Cache:                      3072K
NUMA-Knoten0 CPU(s):           0-3

    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 5500 [1043:1a6d]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
        Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

    00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Broadwell-U Audio Controller [1043:1a6d]
```

Comment: It looks like you've messed up the driver installation after all.

Comment: Make sure you have the CORRECT driver if you downloaded it from nvidia. Remove the one you have now, it apparently doesn't work, and might well be the wrong choice.